# What should I understand by parse error in octave?

Tags: octave

I am getting the error "parse error near line 2" in a 2 line code.

```
A=[12,13;11,14;12,16;17,199;1998,0989];
end
```

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Why did you write `end` on line 2?

Comment: the parser hits "end" before beginning anything which is expected to be "endend"

Answer (score 1):

If I type your line into https://octave-online.net/ I get a similar error.

If I leave off the `end` it prints the matrix.

What's the `end` doing?